# Spring Boot - Multi Document File based on profile for Tomcat 9.0.54

Tags: spring-boot

I have an application.properties file in Spring Boot v2.6.1 where I declared a multi document file notation like below :

```
spring.profiles.active=@spring.profiles.active@

#---
spring.config.activate.on-profile=prod
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
#---
spring.config.activate.on-profile=dev
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect


This works perfectly fine(i.e., picked accordingly) when I run the application in integrated server or IDE by passing spring.profiles.active as prod/dev in VM Arguments.

The same thing doesn't work when I deploy as a war in tomcat by passing in setenv.sh as

export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=prod"

it always picks the "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect" instead of "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect"


Any help?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    After a day of brain storming, finally I found the solution to pick the respective dialect when using multiple datasources based on the profile.
    
    In my case, Primary datasource is Oracle with UCP and secondary is mySQL for Prod & dev profiles respectively.
    
    As per the question, multi document file notation in application.properties works fine in IDE or integrated tomcat but not in External tomcat when deployed as a WAR.
    
    
    Below solution works for both (Integrated & External Tomcat)
    
    
    In MySQL Configuration class, I have set the custom JPA Properties as a tweak.
    
    @Configuration
    @Profile(someConstants.ENV_DEV)
    public class MySqlConfiguration {
    
        private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MySqlConfiguration.class);
    
        @Bean(name = "mySQL")
        @Profile(someConstants.ENV_DEV)
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.mysql.datasource")
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            final String METHOD_NAME = ":: DataSource ::";
            logger.info(METHOD_NAME + "Initialising the MySQL Connection");
            return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        }
    
        @Bean
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.mysql.jpa")
        public JpaProperties jpaProperties() {
            JpaProperties properties = new JpaProperties();
            return properties;
        }
    
    }
    
    In Application.properties
    
    spring.mysql.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect // this for mySQL
    
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect  // this for Oracle
    
    
Moreover, I have done the same setting in setenv.sh file for external tomcat

// for prod
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=prod" 

// for dev
#export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=dev"


    I analysed the logs and now each datasources picks up the respective properties & dialect based on profile, perfectly fine and awesome.
    
    
    Happy Coding..
```